# Excel 'shape' ends up a linked object from VBA

Tags: image, vba, excel

I'm bringing in a shape via code to be a logo at the bottom of a report, but it ends up being handled differently from the normal way Excel handles shapes. My shape disappears if the source (or indeed destination) file is moved - it's handled as though it's a link, so doesn't show, whereas, if I'm using normal "Insert tab ==>Picture" it just keeps the picture visible no matter what.

This is the code I'm using, can anyone see why it's doing it the way it is?

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(MyFileAndPath).Select
Set MyLogo = Selection
'Format the size and position
With MyLogo
   .ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 1#, True, msoScaleFromTopLeft
   .ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 1#, True, msoScaleFromTopLeft
   xWidth = .ShapeRange.Width
   xHeight = .ShapeRange.Height
   xRatio = xWidth / xHeight
   .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   .ShapeRange.Width = 285
   .ShapeRange.Height = 285 / xRatio
   .ShapeRange.Left = shtCover.Range("LogoBotRight").Left + shtCover.Range("LogoBotRight").Width - MyLogo.ShapeRange.Width
   .ShapeRange.Top = shtCover.Range("LogoBotRight").Top + shtCover.Range("LogoBotRight").Height - MyLogo.ShapeRange.Height
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(MyFileAndPath).Select
Set MyLogo = Selection
```

with:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture MyFileAndPath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 70, 70
Set MyLogo = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
```